# Ajax 415 Response - Tango API

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm currently experimenting on [Tango's testing console](https://integration-www.tangocard.com/raas_api_console/v2/) for their API. However, when I open the browser's console on that page and run the following code snippet I  keep getting a 415 error response.

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://integration-api.tangocard.com/raas/v2/customers",
type: "POST",
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic UUFQbGF0Zm9ybTI6YXBZUGZUNkhOT05wRFJVajNDTEdXWXQ3Z3ZJSE9OcERSVVlQZlQ2SGo=' 
},
data: {
    "customerIdentifier": "dummy475",
    "displayName": "dummy475"
},
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
});
```

The authorization and everything else is straight forward, I'm simply using the provided example data. Any ideas why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: you forgot to set the content-type request header - how are you getting around CORS though?

Comment: @JaromandaX For experimenting purposes, I'm just opening up the browser developer tools and running that code snippet within the same page, so it's not cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with the Postman. May be you are missing Content-Type in headers.

```
headers: { 
           'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
         },
```